# Confidentiality is to confidential as integrity is to... what?

Tags: word-choice

In a piece of technical writing I need to write the following sentence:

> [...] as more confidential (or less X) information is
>   [...]

Where X is to integrity as confidential is to confidentiality. However, I'm unable to find a suitable word for X.

Integrity is in the context of [information security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_security#Integrity). I don't think integral is the right word, as that would refer to something being important or essential, right?

Comment: What is wrong with *integral*?  That would be the normal adjective.

Comment: Welcome Mathias, are you using integrity with the meaning of morality, rather than  whole or essential? In which case, perhaps 'ethical'? It might be worth giving the whole sentence so that people can see which meaning of integrity you are aiming for.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! Integrity is in the context of information security (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_security#Integrity). I don't think integral is the right word, as that would refer to something being important or essential, right?

Comment: Hi Mathias, and welcome to Writers. Requests for single words are off-topic for us but acceptable on English SE. This question will likely be migrated there, where the community can help you.

Comment: *Integral* has at its root *integer*, a whole number. Something that is whole is integral. Something can be an integral part of something, but integral implies wholeness. *Integrity* is the quality of being integral. He has integrity. (He's not broken into pieces.) Honor is integral to his character.

Comment: unimpaired is what integrity means (computers). non-degraded. Why not do some reading before asking the question? There are always adjectives in those texts.

Comment: Have you considered reversing the sense of the comparison? Rather than "less X", try "more corrupt", "more suspect", "more degraded", etc. Not sure which is most appropriate to this application.

Comment: [What is the adjective form for the word "integrity?"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5120/what-is-the-adjective-form-for-the-word-integrity) is almost the same question; the only difference is the context in which the word is used.

Comment: Can you give a succinct definition of "integrity" in your context? Pull a quote from the link, or make something up, just give those of us who are better with words than information security a clearer idea of what you want.

Comment: You could use accurate/authentic as in data that has not been tampered with.

Answer (score 1):

In the context of information security, ***[data integrity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_integrity)*** is most often described as:

> the maintenance of, and the assurance of the accuracy and consistency
>   of, data over its entire life-cycle

so the adjective/s to describe data with its integrity intact would be ***accurate and consistent***.

---

However, it needs to be noted that:

> The term is broad in scope and may have widely different meanings
>   depending on the specific context – even under the same general
>   umbrella of computing. It is at times used as a proxy term for data
>   quality,while data validation is a pre-requisite for data
>   integrity.

so the above suggestion may not be applicable in your specific context (of which we know nothing).

---

Going back to the general concept:

> Data integrity is the opposite of data corruption.

This suggest that instead of "less accurate" and/or "less consistent" you could use ***"more corrupt"***.

Answer (score 0):

**confidentiality** - the nature (classification) of a document's information: sensitive, confidential, highly confidential

**confidential** - suffix -ial (like part-ial; of or like a part; of or like confide), from Latin - *con* (with) + *fidel* (trust).

**integrity** - suffix -ity (like par -ity; from *pares* (equal)), the nature of someone or something, and whether that nature is reflective of an element which is *integral* to a system...

**integral** - Those things which are more central or core possess greater prestige and responsibility, and to maintain that office, one must act with *[integrity](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/integrity)*. This breadcrumb-etymology was not widely adopted, hence we end up with islands like "integrity" which do not have common parallels...